# Dragging a UIImageView without having to touch the Image?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

My app has a UIView in which there is a UIImageView. The user needs to be able to move that image, but not necessarily touching on the Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare

```
NSInteger offsetX;
NSInteger offsetY;
```

And implement the following methods in your view controller:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Get touch coordinates in location view
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    //Calculate offset on touches began
    offsetX = touchPoint.x - imageView.frame.origin.x;
    offsetY = touchPoint.y - imageView.frame.origin.y;
}


-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Get touch coordinates in location view
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    //Create new frame with origin offset
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - offsetX, touchPoint.y - offsetY, imageView.bounds.size.width, imageView.bounds.size.height);

    //Set the new frame
    imageView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Comment: Precisely what I wanted! Thanks much for the quick answer!